# How to search multiple columns with one variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search one table, and multiple columns using 1 variable.  My code looks like this:

```
SELECT        lCustomerID, sLastName, sFirstName, sAddress1, sAddress2, 
  sCity, sState, sZipcode , @search AS Expr1
FROM            Customers
WHERE (sLastName = N'Includes @search') 
OR    (sFirstName = N'includes @search') 
AND   (sBarcode = N'includes @search')
```

I want it to include the string not =

Comment: Do you mean to have OR / AND? Or did you mean both to be OR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant to have all ORs, and that "I want it to include the string" means you want a partial match (e.g. a search for "John" yields "Johnson" and "RoJohn"), you are looking for the LIKE keyword:

```
WHERE sLastName  LIKE N'%' + @search + '%'
   OR sFirstName LIKE N'%' + @search + '%'
   OR sBarCode   LIKE N'%' + @search + '%';
```